# Optimal Area within two equal intersecting circles and its expectation

Tags: geometry, probability-distributions, optimization, circles

1. For any point within AXBY, find the area of the circle ACBD which yields the smallest value for the ratio  $ (Ao + oB) / AB $.
2. For any point o within ACBD what is the expectation of this distance i.e E(r).

NB: The two big circles are of the same size and points A and B are at the centre of the two circles. AB is the radius of both circles.

In case no such circle exist can we prove this for any area (such as eclipse) within AXBY i.e taking a stopover at any point within the area would yield a shorter distance as compared to any point outside this area  [image: picture]

Comment: So you arbitrarily overlap two circles with the same size, and then connecting the two centres by a straight line which intersect the circumference at $A$ and $B$ respectively. The first question you want to ask is how to choose the length of $AB$ (the degree of overlap) to minimize (the expected value of ?) the random ratio $(Ao + oB) /(AB)$

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes the circles are of the same size and points A and B are at the centre of the two circles. AB is the radius of both circles. I have edited the question for better clarity

Comment: Thanks for your comment. There are two connected questions the first is an area ACBD within the overlap where the distance from A to any point within ACBD + the distance from that arbitrary point to B will give the minimum ratio of A-to that point to-B divided by distance AB. In other words, journeying from A to B through any point outside the arbitrary circle ACBD, will take a longer distance than journeying from A to B within the arbitrary circle ACBD

Comment: The expected value of any arbitrary distance r within the optimal area ACBD

Comment: As first I only think that the points $AB$ just lies on the line connecting the two centres, but may not be exactly be the centres such that you are allow to control the degree of overlap. If you fix the relative positions of the two circles, then the area of the circle $ACBD$ (which required to be inscribed inside the overlapped region) is fixed? So how does this used to optimize that expected ratio?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The small circle inscribed in AXBY is just to conceptualize that an area of a cirle exists within the overlapping region which satisfy the constraint in the question

Comment: If you require the small circle to pass through both points $A$ and $B$, and it is not allow to cut across the circumferences of the big circles, then there is only one circle satisfy the constraint?

Comment: Yes, and that is the circle I am looking for its area and the expectation of a a point uniformly distributed within it.

Answer (score 1):

For a given radius, the best circle is centered at the midpoint of $AB$.  You can justify this by noting that among the points $o$ a given distance off the segment $AB$ the one with smallest distance $Ao+oB$ is above or below the midpoint of $AB$.  The sum of distances is monotonically increasing as you leave the midpoint, so having the set of points symmetric around the midpoint is a good thing.  It seems likely that for a given point the circle with smallest expectation is one of zero radius, just the point.  The surprising thing is the set of points with minimum sum of distances is not just the midpoint of $AB$ but the whole segment.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ross Millikan, if I get your well described point above, does it mean we can have an eclipse instead of a circle inscribed with AB as the shorter length while the longer length passes through the centre.

Comment: Do you mean something like the diagram in the edit? i.e the optimal area will look like the eclipse ACBD?

Comment: Basically, points $o$ near $AB$ will have a shorter distance than point farther away.  Among the points the same distance from $AB$ the point nearest the center of $AB$ will have the shortest distance.  When you talk about networks and draw in the Euclidean plane I suspect you are missing the point.  Networks are not Euclidean.  Some distance are much easier to traverse than others for networks.

Comment: Thanks @Ross, I appreciate your interest and your response had helped to understand this problem better. This is the point. We have two devices, one at A and the other at B. Whenever the device at A finds that there is another device say Q within the area AXBY, with a distance smaller than AB, it sends to Q as a relay to B. Say AB=5 and AQ=7, while QB=4. The problem is that the distance covered by Q to B is now greater than the distance AB which is not energy efficient from the perspective of device Q. The objective is to find the area within AXBY where distances AQ + QB is optimal.

Comment: The triangle inequality guarantees that passing through Q is never better for total distance than going directly.  It is as good if Q is on AB.I repeat my claim that networks do not reflect Euclidean space.  Some links are more efficient than the distance indicates, either because they have a better link or because they are less busy.  The distances are also not what Euclid would calculate because you have to go along the wires that exist.   If you are interested in network performance you are asking the wrong question entirely.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is based on an assumption in a Journal paper. The idea is to improve on this assumptions. Regarding the link quality, all those can be taken care of within the assumptions. The system is not a wired system but wireless and although, link quality may vary. For performance analysis it could be assumed that they are the same for tractability.