# Travelling Challenge

Tags: geometry, circles

In a bid to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2583923/optimal-area-within-two-equal-intersecting-circles-and-its-expectation?), I stumbled on a clue which led to a different interesting question. It is possible a theorem already exist addressing this, but I do not know one of such.

In layman terms: can we prove that if I am to travel from point A to point B taking a stopover at any point (say 'o') within area $ACBD$, I would travel a shorter distance as compared to when I stop over at any point outside the area of $ACBD$ (within $AXBY$)?  [image]

Comment: Please if you have any further questions ask, I am willing to clarify. If this question has been answered before, please include the link so I may delete the question.

Comment: "Triangle inequality."

Comment: @Abdulhameed What happens if $O_1$ is located $0.01$ units directly above $A$ (technically outside the circle), while $O_2$ is located at $C$? Won't the path of $O_1$ be shorter than $O_2$?

Comment: For a fixed total travel distance, the locus of possible stopover points is an ellipse with foci at $A$ and $B$.  That ellipse is going to intersect both $ACBD$ and $AXBY \setminus ACBD$.

Comment: I appreciate your comments, but I think a schematic diagram would help me understand this better as I don't get this well. I'll appreciate your input.

Comment: @Abdulhameed The path $ACB$ has length $l_1=R \sqrt{2}\,$. The path $AEB$ where $E$ is the point on arc $AC$ such that $\angle EBA = \pi / 6$ has length $l_2 = R(\sin(\pi/6) + \cos (\pi/6))$ $= R(1+\sqrt{3}) /2\,$. Clearly $l_2 \lt l_1\,$, now "push" point $C$ slightly downwards and point $E$ slightly outwards, then the inequality will still hold, and you get an "inside" path that is longer than a "partially outside" path.

Comment: Thanks @dxiv, after looking at your insightful explanation above. I think you mean that its possible to have a point 'o' outside the circle ($E$ in your case) with a shorter ratio $Ao + oB$ as compared to the ratio in the circle.

Comment: I think the same question has been asked at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/289541/optimal-traversal-distance-within-two-intersecting-circles only without the diagram to clarify matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible unless you allow the degenerate region that is the line segment AB.  Let us scale the figure so $AB=1$.  Following Tony Mak's suggestion, suppose there is a point $O$ in the region that has $AO+OB=1+x$ where we assume $x$ is small.  There is a point $P$ outside the region that is $\frac x2$ above $A$.  $AP+PB=\frac x2+\sqrt {1+\frac {x^2}4} \lt 1+x = AO+OB$

Comment: Thanks Ross Millikan, I have tried to follow your contribution and  I liked it. By outside the region, you mean outside $ACBD$? Also, what would be the new hypotenuse of the triangle $APB$

Comment: Yes, it is outside $ACBD$ because $ACBD$ curves in when it leaves $A$.  The hypotenuse is $\sqrt{1+(\frac x2)^2}$ which is the second term in my distance formula.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Then angle $PAB$ becomes a right angled triangle. Sorry, I just want to ensure its clear. The second part of the question is that is it possible to have another area which satisfies this condition say an eclipse etc. The question is motivated by a network problem

Comment: Yes, $PAB$ is right.  I chose that $P$ because it was easy to calculate the distances and it met my need.  My proof works for any area larger than the segment $AB$ that doesn't have vertical sides at $A,B$ of finite length.  Even if you have those, I can find a point just outside $A$ along $AB$ that meets my needs.  I just need to keep it close enough to $A$.